# How to get cookies in Java?

Tags: java, cookies, asp-classic

I'm implementing a project from ASP that cross to a Java program.  In a Java class, what I want is to get the cookies that is set by the ASP program.

Is that possible?

If so, I have this code at hand but its not working....

```
class AfficheMonCookie extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException{
        String Valeur = "";
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        for(int i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            Cookie MonCookie = cookies[i];
            if (MonCookie.getName().equals("FXA")) {
                Valeur = cookies[i].getValue();
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: *How* is it not working? What version of Java? What is your servlet container?

Answer (score 0):

Use a network monitor tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect the cookies set by the ASP site (`Set-Cookie` response header) and to see if the cookies make it to the Servlet HTTP request (`Cookie` request header).

> > *Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy* which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and [other machines]. Fiddler allows you to inspect traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" [or just inspect] with incoming or outgoing data.

Remember that the cookies *come from the client* (e.g. web-browser) and are only sent for matching domains *and* paths -- it may be possible they were/are never sent to the Java server at all.

Happy coding.

Comment: Hello

How to check if the cookies are sent to Java server/ made it the the Servlet HTTP request?

thanks

Jason

Comment: @RJ Use a network monitor tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)... run it on the test machine that first contacts the ASP site and then the Servlet.